# How I change the colors of my buttons between one array colors?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying change colors of my buttons from one array colors pre-defined. Like this:

```
  String[] colors = {"#2962ff", "#00bfa5", "#ff6d00", "#aa00ff"};
        Random random = new Random();
        String myRandString = random.nextInt(colors.length);

        // My Buttons
        inGridLayout00.setBackgroundColor(myRandString);
        inGridLayout01.setBackgroundColor(myRandString);
        inGridLayout10.setBackgroundColor(myRandString);
        inGridLayout11.setBackgroundColor(myRandString);
```

But I don't know how fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing great however you need to pass the random number back to array and get the color for that random index number

```js
  int[] colors = {#2962ff, #00bfa5, #ff6d00, #aa00ff};
        Random random = new Random();
        int myRandString = random.nextInt(colors.length);

        // My Buttons
        inGridLayout00.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[myRandString]));
        inGridLayout01.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[myRandString]));
        inGridLayout10.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[myRandString]));
        inGridLayout11.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[myRandString]));
```

All you have to do is

```
setBackgroundColor(colors[myRandString]);
```

which gets the color for the random index number

Comment: Also notice that `setBackgroundColor` takes a `int` parameter, you should change `colors` from `String` to `int`, and `"#2962ff"` to `0x2962ff`, and change `myRandString` to `int` too.

Comment: Thanks @RayWan, it's working great, but all buttons are always the same color. I wanted each one to have a different color every time with onclick action. How I fix this?

Comment: @LuisBalmant thats because you get one random value for example myRandString = "5" and then use that for all of your buttons. What you can do is have 4 different "int myRandString = random.nextInt(colors.length);"
So you get a different number every time. Or do them inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Siyavash answer..
You should change this part

```
String myRandString = random.nextInt(colors.length);
```

to

```
int myRandString = random.nextInt(colors.length);
```

And also

```
   inGridLayout00.setBackgroundColor(colors[myRandString]);
```

to

```
inGridLayout00.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[myRandString]));
```